# Cannot resolve keyword 'article' into field

Tags: python, django

I know that there are multiple questions about this already but none of them resolves my problem.

I have split my models into multiple files under models folder, viz., models/articles.py, models/core.py etc.

When I try executing

```
User.objects.annotate(my_count=Count('article'))
```

django gives me the following error:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'articles' into field. Choices are: access, cfi_store_item_likes, collaborators, comment, date_joined, documentation, email, emailaddress, first_name, groups, id, images, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, listing, logentry, makey, makey_removed, newproduct, note, password, productdescription, productimage, profile, socialaccount, space_admins, space_members, textdocumentation, tutorial, user_permissions, userflags, username, video

I have the following code in models/abstract.py

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    added_time = models.DateTimeField('added time')
    is_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'catalog'
```

I have the following in models/article.py

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    url = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    recommendation = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleTag, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, null=True, blank=True)
    new_user = models.ForeignKey('NewUser', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'catalog'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title + ' (' + self.url + ')'
```

I have the following in models/core.py, along with many other models which have been listed as the available options.

```
class Tutorial(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="tutorialimages",
                                    null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'catalog'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

Why is django not picking up my ForeignKey to User from models from rest of the files? Why is it picking it up only from core.py?

I have posted the models and stacktrace at http://pastebin.com/v6hFdvAC and http://pastebin.com/nxYktwHn.

Comment: There is some weird thing in your traceback. are your sure you don't have a typo in your code? 'articles' in traceback and 'article' in your orm query

Comment: That was a typo. I mistyped 'articles' in the query. Later changed it to 'article'. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: let me ask a silly question: are you sure you have the synced db with your model? can you check you db schema for "Article" and see if it does have a user_id field? I just try the similar case on my project, which works fine.

Comment: I use postgresql. I checked the `app_article` table and it has a field `user_id` which is a foreign key to `auth_user(id)`

Comment: well, without the actual env for debugging, it is really hard to say what is going here. What I can say is that your 'Article' model and your 'User' is not connected. You can try 'User._meta.get_all_related_objects()' to say if 'Article' is in the return tuple (I suspect it doesn't). It is really hard to tell what would cause this.

Comment: @JerryMeng, as pointed in the comments for the answer below, it is not there in the tuple returned. :-(

How can I debug this?

Comment: well, as I said, it is extremely hard to debug this kind of tricky issue without the interactive env. Sorry pal, I don't know what to do to help you:(

Comment: I have the exact same issue right now. I hope you remember the solution after years. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because not all users have an article. If you see, your user foreign key in `Article Class` can be null.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

then when Django tries to apply the count on null values, it raises an error.

Maybe you can use somehthing like that:

```
User.objects.objects.filter(article__isnull=False).count()
```

Comment: `Tutorial Class` also can be null. But the query:

`User.objects.annotate(my_count=Count('tutorial'))`

works fine.

I tried running with `article__isnull=False` filter, but ended up with the same 'cannot resolve keyword' error.

Another thing I noticed is that 'article' does not show up in the list of `related_objects`.

`User._meta.get_all_related_objects()` returns the following:

`[<RelatedObject: catalog:comment related to user>,
  <RelatedObject: catalog:documentation related to user>,
  <RelatedObject: catalog:image related to user>,
  <RelatedObject: admin:logentry related to user>]`

Comment: @SiddardhaG did you add that article attribute after create your database? did you run syncdb?

Comment: Yes. I use south for migrations. And everything seems to be in sync. I am able to run the rest of the queries. This particular query itself is screwing up.

Comment: @SiddardhaG I think, in the case of `tutorial class` there is not null value, but in article case yes, and because that it raises an error.